# Use SUM with UNION ALL in one line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following `query`:

```
    SELECT SUM(totalCantidad) AS totalCantidad,
           SUM(totalPrecio) AS totalPrecio
    FROM(
           SELECT  SUM(dt1.cantidad) AS totalCantidad,
                   SUM(dt1.cantidad*dt1.precio) AS totalPrecio
           FROM Det_materiales dt1
           INNER JOIN Materiales ma ON ma.factura=dt1.factura
           WHERE ma.factura='1848'
         UNION ALL
           SELECT SUM(dt2.cantidad) AS totalCantidad,
                  SUM(dt2.cantidad*p.precio) AS totalPrecio
           FROM Det_mate2 dt2
           INNER JOIN Materiales ma ON ma.factura=dt2.factura
           INNER JOIN Partes p ON p.cod_parte=dt2.cod_parte
           WHERE ma.factura='1848'
       )x GROUP BY totalCantidad
```

it returns me this:

[image]

Is there a way to generate both SUM () in a single line, like this:

```
totalCantidad-----totalPrecio
16909             63550,169
```

Also I need to print data from `FROM` but I don't know how to display it, in other words I need like this:

```
factura-----other data-----totalCantidad-----totalPrecio
1848         xxxxxx          16909             63550,169
```

Any idea to do this?

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, there was a large hint that you should also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality between them differs greatly. It's a waste of both your time and ours for you not to do so, as either you'll get answers you can't use because they're for a different database or we'll waste our time answering your question only to find out it won't work for you. Please [edit] your post to add that DBMS-specific tag. Use only the tag for the actual DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - be removing `GROUP BY totalCantidad`

```
 SELECT factura,SUM(totalCantidad) AS totalCantidad,
           SUM(totalPrecio) AS totalPrecio
    FROM(
           SELECT  ma.factura,SUM(dt1.cantidad) AS totalCantidad,
                   SUM(dt1.cantidad*dt1.precio) AS totalPrecio
           FROM Det_materiales dt1
           INNER JOIN Materiales ma ON ma.factura=dt1.factura
           WHERE ma.factura='1848' group by ma.factura
         UNION ALL
           SELECT ma.factura, SUM(dt2.cantidad) AS totalCantidad,
                  SUM(dt2.cantidad*p.precio) AS totalPrecio
           FROM Det_mate2 dt2
           INNER JOIN Materiales ma ON ma.factura=dt2.factura
           INNER JOIN Partes p ON p.cod_parte=dt2.cod_parte
           WHERE ma.factura='1848' group by ma.factura
       )x group by factura
```